# Setblock Direction For Redstone Torches (Minecraft 1.13)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Previously before the Minecraft 1.13 release, you used to be able to use

```
/setblock 373 42 269 redstone_torch 2
```

and be able to choose the rotation of the torch you're setting. However, with this new update with changes to Minecraft Commands, you can't set the rotation of the redstone torch just by placing for example, a '2' next to redstone_torch.

So how would I be able to set the rotation of a redstone torch via the /setblock command in the new 1.13 update?

> See attached pictures for further explanation  https://prnt.sc/kbyjke and
>   https://prnt.sc/kbyjo6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1.13 the block ID you'd want would be `redstone_wall_torch`.

Then for the rotation, numeric block metadata has been removed. You must instead use [blockstates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_states), which are specified after the block ID in a `[key=value,key=value]` format. In this case:

```
setblock ~ ~ ~ redstone_wall_torch[facing=east]
```

You can find a block's blockstates on the F3 screen when looking at it:

[image: F3 targeted block]

Or, 1.13's command suggestions/completions can be helpful:

[image: Tab-complete blockstates]

Answer (score 0):

```
/setblock 373 42 269 minecraft:redstone_wall_torch{facing:south}
```

as of 1.13?
oops, I was using fill:

```
/fill 373 42 269 minecraft:redstone_wall_torch{facing:south}
```